# Export shapefile to MapInfo file using Python OGR

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, mapinfo, tab

I'm trying to save/copy a shapefile to a .tab format with Python OGR.
Every attempts give me the following error:

> RuntimeError: CreateFeature() failed: cannot re-write already existing
> feature 1

When I try to export the shapefile to another shapefile it's working perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
import os, sys
from osgeo import ogr

path_script = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
shp_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_script), "shapefiles", "arrondissement_ExportFeature.shp")


ogr.UseExceptions()

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

inds = driver.Open(shp_path, 0)
if inds is None:
    sys.Exit("impossible douvrir le fichier")

inLayer = inds.GetLayer(0)

driver_out = ogr.GetDriverByName("MapInfo File")
outds = driver_out.CreateDataSource("outLast.tab")

outlyr = outds.CreateLayer("outLast", inLayer.GetSpatialRef(), ogr.wkbPolygon)
outlyr.CreateFields(inLayer.schema)

out_defn = outlyr.GetLayerDefn()
out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_defn)


for in_feat in inLayer:

    geom=in_feat.geometry()
    out_feat.SetGeometry(geom)

    for i in range(in_feat.GetFieldCount()):

        value = in_feat.GetField(i)
        out_feat.SetField(i, value)

    outlyr.CreateFeature(out_feat)

del inds
del outds
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
`out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_defn)` has to be inside the loop `for in_feat in inLayer:`